# add/delete Multiple markers in android map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android; I want to add multiple markers on my map by touching it and whenever I touched the marked place again, the marker disappears. 
My main intention is that lat/lang sent to a server by adding a marker and lat/lang deleted from database in server when I touch the mark for second time.

May you please guide me to add all these functions? how I should start and what I should do?

Thank you so much

Comment: try this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143129/add-marker-on-android-google-map-via-touch-or-tap>.

Comment: Use onMarkerClick listener to add and remove markers.

Comment: Follow this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#googlemaps_activity)

Comment: what you have done so far? post in question

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker) on how to add markers. Here's a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171429/add-marker-on-touched-location-using-google-map-in-android) which might help.

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            lstLatLngs.add(point);
            map.clear();
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));
        }
    });
```

You can also check on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951852/adding-marker-google-map-using-data-in-database) on how to add marker in Google maps using data in database. Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe my question seems silly but excuse me ecause I am a newbie: Where exactly I should add this code? to "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {"     or to  "public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {"   this part?